# Modifications of BFS/DFS to check simple paths

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I have to design an algorithm as from BFS or DFS to do the following, given G=(V,E) a directed graph:

Check whether there is at most one simple path from *s* to any other vertex u in V. This algorithm has to be on O(|V|+|E|).

And from the previous algorithm, I have to design another one O(|V||E|) algorithm to check whether there is at most one simple path between any two vertices *u* and *v*.

I hope you can help me! Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: What if all the edges on the path from **s** to **u** are [cut edges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_%28graph_theory%29) (bridge)? What if any of them are not cut edge? :)

Note: We can find all the bridges in a graph O(V+E) time

Comment: Nice solution!I read up on the wiki link, but the linear time algorithm described there, I couldn't get it.Could it maybe describe it in simple terms?

Comment: @Aravind: You can look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218746/bridges-in-a-connected-graph) By the way if you like the solution, why not vote it up? :) That's how another one can find the answer interesting :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @MuhammedHedayet!! This is very useful. With the code you posted before, I can find all the bridges, but, how can I determine whether the path between _s_ to any vertex which is only composed of bridges?

Comment: @Stratford: A simple solution can be like the following: first mark all the edges those are bridge. And while finding the bridges you can find the parent for every node. So you can start from **u** to reach **s** following the parent node at every step. While following the path, simply check if the edge from **a** to **b** is a bridge or not, where **a** and **b** are two vertices on the path from **u** to **s** and **b** is parent of **a**.