# Bridge in a graph that makes the graph disconnected

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

I am working on programming where I need to find the articulation points of a graph (nodes such that removing any of them makes the graph disconnected)

For example, I have these links:

**Example 1**

```
[[0,1], [0,2], [1,3], [2,3], [5,6], [3,4]]
```

[image]

```
The answer should be [2,3,5], because removing these nodes makes the graph disconnected.
```

**Explanation:**

```
If I remove node 2 here, the graph becomes 2 parts 0,1,3,4 and 5,6
If I remove node 3 here, the graph becomes 2 parts 0,1,2,5,6 and 4
If I remove node 5 here, the graph becomes 2 parts 0,1,2,3,4 and 6
```

**Example 2:**

```
[[1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,5], [6,3]]
```

[image]

```
The output should be: [2, 3, 4]
```

**Explanation:**

```
If I remove node 2 here, the graph becomes 2 parts 1, and 3,4,5,6
If I remove node 3 here, the graph becomes 3 parts 1,2 and 6 and 4,5
If I remove node 4 here, the graph becomes 2 parts 1,2,3,6 and 5
```

How to achieve this in a Java program?

Comment: I think this is related with "min cut" problem https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-cut-in-a-directed-graph/

Comment: There are several well-known linear-time algorithms to do this; some can be found in other answers to [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917290/how-can-i-find-bridges-in-an-undirected-graph) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11221469/15472)

Comment: I've removed the language-specific tag from the question. Since the lack of an attempt included in the question. Even after which, it's worth asking a question after an attempt that you've made and sharing where did it fail or raised a doubt in your mind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bridges in a connected graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218746/bridges-in-a-connected-graph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
import static java.lang.Math.min;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArticulationPointsAdjacencyList {

  private int n, id, rootNodeOutcomingEdgeCount;
  private boolean solved;
  private int[] low, ids;
  private boolean[] visited, isArticulationPoint;
  private List<List<Integer>> graph;

  public ArticulationPointsAdjacencyList(List<List<Integer>> graph, int n) {
    if (graph == null || n <= 0 || graph.size() != n) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    this.graph = graph;
    this.n = n;
  }

  // Returns the indexes for all articulation points in the graph even if the
  // graph is not fully connected.
  public boolean[] findArticulationPoints() {
    if (solved) return isArticulationPoint;

    id = 0;
    low = new int[n]; // Low link values
    ids = new int[n]; // Nodes ids
    visited = new boolean[n];
    isArticulationPoint = new boolean[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (!visited[i]) {
        rootNodeOutcomingEdgeCount = 0;
        dfs(i, i, -1);
        isArticulationPoint[i] = (rootNodeOutcomingEdgeCount > 1);
      }
    }

    solved = true;
    return isArticulationPoint;
  }

  private void dfs(int root, int at, int parent) {

    if (parent == root) rootNodeOutcomingEdgeCount++;

    visited[at] = true;
    low[at] = ids[at] = id++;

    List<Integer> edges = graph.get(at);
    for (Integer to : edges) {
      if (to == parent) continue;
      if (!visited[to]) {
        dfs(root, to, at);
        low[at] = min(low[at], low[to]);
        if (ids[at] <= low[to]) {
          isArticulationPoint[at] = true;
        }
      } else {
        low[at] = min(low[at], ids[to]);
      }
    }
  }

  /* Graph helpers */

  // Initialize a graph with 'n' nodes.
  public static List<List<Integer>> createGraph(int n) {
    List<List<Integer>> graph = new ArrayList<>(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) graph.add(new ArrayList<>());
    return graph;
  }

  // Add an undirected edge to a graph.
  public static void addEdge(List<List<Integer>> graph, int from, int to) {
    graph.get(from).add(to);
    graph.get(to).add(from);
  }

  /* Example usage: */

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    testExample2();
  }

  private static void testExample1() {
    int n = 7;
    List < List < Integer >> graph = createGraph (n);

    addEdge (graph, 0, 1);
    addEdge (graph, 0, 2);
    addEdge (graph, 1, 3);
    addEdge (graph, 2, 3);
    addEdge (graph, 2, 5);
    addEdge (graph, 5, 6);
    addEdge (graph, 3, 4);

    ArticulationPointsAdjacencyList solver = new ArticulationPointsAdjacencyList(graph, n);
    boolean[] isArticulationPoint = solver.findArticulationPoints();

    // Prints:
    // Node 2 is an articulation
    // Node 3 is an articulation
    // Node 5 is an articulation
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      if (isArticulationPoint[i]) System.out.printf("Node %d is an articulation\n", i);
  }

  private static void testExample2() {
    int n = 7;
    List < List < Integer >> graph = createGraph (n);

    addEdge (graph, 1, 2);
    addEdge (graph, 2, 3);
    addEdge (graph, 3, 4);
    addEdge (graph, 3, 6);
    addEdge (graph, 4, 5);


    ArticulationPointsAdjacencyList solver = new ArticulationPointsAdjacencyList(graph, n);
    boolean[] isArticulationPoint = solver.findArticulationPoints();

    // Prints:
    // Node 2 is an articulation
    // Node 3 is an articulation
    // Node 4 is an articulation
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      if (isArticulationPoint[i]) System.out.printf("Node %d is an articulation\n", i);
  }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/williamfiset/Algorithms/blob/master/com/williamfiset/algorithms/graphtheory/ArticulationPointsAdjacencyList.java

Comment: Can you please give some explanation and approach to solve this program

Comment: @learner https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZXi1unBdJA this is the video talking about how it works, hopefully, it useful for you.

Comment: @learner if you think my post answered your question, could you send the award bounty?

Answer (score 1):

There are different algorithms used to find the nodes such that if removed they make the graph disconnected (called articulation points).

Here I explain one of them and I provide some code that implements it:

## Tarjan Algorithm

Given a graph [image] we want to find all the [image] such that if [image] is removed from [image] the graph become disconnected

The first observation is that the a (weak) connected component in a directed graph is equal to a connected component in the same graph, but where the edges are undirected. So for simplicity we consider [image] as an undirected graph.

### Algorithm description

On the graph we run a pre-order Depth First Search (DFS) visit where for any node [image] we assign 2 values, let's call it `pre` and `low`. `pre` represent the instant when the node is visited and `low` the instant of the lowest reachable node from [image].

The visit works in this way:

At every step of the visit both `pre` and `low` of [image] are set to the next value of `pre`. Then if we find that a cycle is being closed we set `low` to `pre` of the start cycle node. `low` value is transmitted to parent through DFS backtracking.

When the DFS finish for every couple of nodes [image] such that [image] and [image] are neighbor and `low` value of [image] is greater or equal to the `pre` value of [image] then [image] is an articulation point.
For this there is an exception: the root of the DFS spanning tree is an articulation point only if it has more than 1 children

### Example

(In the graph P obviously means `pre` and L means `low`)

At first `pre` and `low` of every vertex are set to a default value (let's say -1)

[image]

We start from node 0 and set his `pre` and `low`

[image]

We go to node 1 and set his `pre` and `low`

[image]

We can go to 2 or 3, we decide to go to 2 and set his `pre` and `low`

[image]

We can go to 4 or 5, we decide to go to 4 and set his `pre` and `low`

[image]

We go to 3 and set his `pre` and `low`

[image]

We see that 1 is alredy visited; that means it is a cycle, so we update `low` of 3 to `pre` of 1

[image]

Through backtrack we return to 4 and update his `low` value

[image]

Through backtrack we return to 2 and update his `low` value

[image]

Now we go to 5 and set his `pre` and `low`

[image]

Through backtrack we return to 2, but there's nothing to do.
We returned from 5 so his `low` value is fixed and is greater than `pre` value of 2; so 2 is an articulation point

[image]

Through backtrack we return to 1, and there's nothing to do.
We returned from 2 so his `low` value is fixed and is equal to the `pre` value of 1; so 1 is an articulation point

[image]

Through backtrack we return to 0, but there's nothing to do.
We returned from 1 so his `low` value is fixed and is greater than `pre` value of 0; but 0 is the root and has only one child; so it isn't an articulation point

[image]

So we have found the answer: `[1, 2]`

### Code

Here is a simple really easy to understand snippet of code (C++) extracted from Competitive Programming Handbook by S. Halim and F. Halim and modified by me. 
It is not very adapt to "real word application" (for example because it uses global variables) but it is ok for competitive programming and explaining due to his brevity and clearness.

```cpp
const int UNVISITED = -1;
vector<int> dfs_low;
vector<int> dfs_pre;
int dfsNumberCounter;
int rootChildren;
vector<vector<int>> AdjList;
vector<int> articulation_vertex;

// This function is the DFS that implement Tarjan algoritm
void articulationPoint(int u) {
  dfs_low[u] = dfs_pre[u] = dfsNumberCounter++; // dfs_low[u] <= dfs_pre[u]
  for (int j = 0; j < (int)AdjList[u].size(); j++) {
    int v = AdjList[u][j];
    if (dfs_pre[v] == UNVISITED) { // a tree edge
      dfs_parent[v] = u;
      if (u == dfsRoot) rootChildren++; // special case if u is a root

      articulationPoint(v);

      if (dfs_low[v] >= dfs_pre[u]) // for articulation point
        articulation_vertex[u] = true;  // store this information first
      dfs_low[u] = min(dfs_low[u], dfs_low[v]); // update dfs_low[u]
    }
    else if (v != dfs_parent[u]) // a back edge and not direct cycle
      dfs_low[u] = min(dfs_low[u], dfs_pre[v]); // update dfs_low[u]
} }


// Some driver code
int main() {
  ...  //Init of variables and store of the graph inside AdjList is omitted
  ...  // V is the number of nodes
  dfsNumberCounter = 0;
  dfs_pre.assign(V, UNVISITED);
  dfs_low.assign(V, 0);
  dfs_parent.assign(V, 0);
  articulation_vertex.assign(V, 0);
  rootChildren = 0;
  articulationPoint(0);
  if (root_children > 1) {
    articulation_vertex[0] = false;
  }

  printf("Articulation Points:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
  if (articulation_vertex[i])
    printf(" Vertex %d\n", i);
}
```